# how to store XML files in hadoop?

Tags: xml, hdfs

I have installed hadoop-2.2.0 on ubuntu 12.04.
Now I want to store xml files of 2-4 KB. Can anyone guide me that how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formate your namenode...Start hadoop system and then...

just to store file, you can use

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal File.xml /
```

To check your file is stored on HDFS run this... or in web-browser type this URL "hostname:50070" - hostname==IP address of machine on which hadoop namenode is installed. (if this is not a single node cluster).

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

To read file on HDFS from shell

```
hadoop fs -cat /file.xml
```